# Unity: Ballistic Vector

Tags: vector, unity-game-engine, raycasting

This is a first person shooter game where I am trying to launch a projectile from a moving player. The launch direction depends on where i click on the screen. The "launcher" has a fixed fire strength, which means that the projectile if fired more horizontally will travel further before hitting the ground, likewise a projectile fired in a more upwards direction will go higher but will have travelled less horizontally when it hits the ground due to gravity. The firing vector is determined by where the finger touches the screen, and then multipled by a public parameter "firingstrength". Make sense so far?

What I am confused about is how to get the position of the finger on the screen, which i use to calculate the "vector" to apply to the projectile.

I have imagined doing this (I am new to Unity) by the following:

Empty object (Player): Contains

1. movement scripts
2. Camera
3. Invisble inverted sphere which surrounds the camera, and I use this sphere to pick up the mouse clicks (i.e when i click on the screen the game should detect where on the inside of the sphere I have clicked on, in order to calculate a vector between the camera position and the sphere wall that i clicked on)

Once i have the vector, i just multiply it by a "firingstrength variable and apply it to a projectile that originates from camera position.

Does this make sense or is there a better way to do this?

Kevin

Comment: do you need to shoot the projectile like slingshot? click, drag then release? you only said you want to detect touch on the screen and that where you touch on the screen determines the force of the projectile....so what determines what part of the screen has more strength than the other part? I understand the question but the logic is not good

Comment: The force of the projectile is always the same regardless of direction.
Hence you could think of the end point vector in all directions creating an imaginary sphere around the player.

What i am hoping to do from a limited experience standpoint, is to determine the initial vector of movement when firing, and from that i need to determine where i clicked on the screen.. .make sense?

Comment: And from what I read somewhere, in order to determine where the screen was clicked, the click needs to be registered by an object, not just empty space, and it is this concept that i'm not sure how to implement

Comment: A good game to compare this with would be "Smash hit"

Comment: Oh...for the hit game, the upper side of the screen = higher strength. lower part of the screen = lower strength. Is this what you are asking?

Answer (score 0):

You do not need a sphere just use `Input.mousePosition` and construct a ray from it using `ScreenPointToRay()`. Than you just use `ray.Direction` to get `Vector3` from your camera position.

```
 Ray ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);
 Vector3 shootVector = ray.Diraction;
```

This should do the trick.
For touch interface:

```
Ray ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.GetTouch(0).position);
Vector3 shootVector = ray.Diraction;
```